# AlarmManager schedule to run every 10 minute from 9AM to 4PM

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I would like it to schedule to run every 10 mins everyday repetitively.
Below is the code which executes the pending intent set to it.

The problem is this runs every 10 mins through out the day rather only to run in specific time window which is **9AM to 4PM**.

Any help appreciated in regards to the AlarmManager to fire repetitively in a particular time window.

Below is my current code:

```
        int MILLISECOND_PER_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
        int frequencyInMinutes = 10;// 10 mins interval
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), (frequencyInMinutes * MILLISECOND_PER_MINUTE), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this by using set time and make checks according to need. Start alarm at 9am then cancel at 4.
Check it in your receiver what is time, if 4 is there then cancel the alarm.

```
openTimePickerDialog(false);


private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
AndroidTimeActivity.this, 
onTimeSetListener, 
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
is24r);
timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

timePickerDialog.show();

}

OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
= new OnTimeSetListener(){

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
//Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

setAlarm(calSet);
}};

 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

 textAlarmPrompt.setText(
 "\n\n***\n"
 + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
 + "***\n");

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),   RQS_1, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager =    (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can put a specific time period  condition  and then put your code

```
int MILLISECOND_PER_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
        int frequencyInMinutes = 10;// 10 mins interval
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), (frequencyInMinutes * MILLISECOND_PER_MINUTE), pendingIntent);
```

in it.
Take specific current time and check it by putting the conditions

Comment: Then you need to introduce another alarmManager that kicks off this  alarmManager through a broadcast receiver which is not ideal. Also, Can you elaborate bit more if you I am missing something?